# screen - sent bash to background?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, gnu-screen

So I was working on homework on my school's unix server and I think I totally messed up a screen session. I was going a little trigger/keyboard happy in vim and accidentally did `:w2` instead of just `:w`, so I sent vim to the background (ctrl+Z) and went to go delete it. Except that in my mad typing, I think I may have actually hit ctrl+Z twice, and... send the bash prompt to the background?? I'm not really sure what happened, I just know that I got out of vim but didn't get back to the prompt. I tried pretty much everything I could think of short of terminating the screen session, including a lot of random keysmashing.

The last usable output in the screen session is:

```
lcm72@tux1:~/cs380/SlidingBrickPuzzle (master)$ fg
vim BoardState.java

[1]+  Stopped                 vim BoardState.java
^Zls
```

I've started a new screen session to continue working on the homework, but if anyone could help me understand what the heck happened here (I didn't think it was possible to ctrl+Z bash?) -- so I can recover it or even just not make the same mistake again -- I would appreciate it.

Comment: invoke `fg %1` - it will bring your task back from backgound

Answer (score 1):

If you typed <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, you could have suspended `screen`, not your whole screen session, just the `screen` *viewer*, the one that attaches to the script session to display it in the host terminal.

If that's the case `ps -flHC screen` would show you one `screen` process that's in the `T` state. You could try and resume it with `kill -CONT` if the host terminal is still there, or just kill it and re-attach to your screen session from another terminal with `screen -x`.